# how to select all elements having same class except the clicked element

Tags: jquery

Here, all the dropdown have the same class. when i click on particular dropdown i just want to slidetoggle for that dropdown and if any other dropdown is slidedown then slide it up so that the current dropdown can only be slided down. I am just confused between the jquery selector.

```
        $(".dropdown").click(function () {
            $(".dropdown-menu",this).slideToggle();
            $('.dropdown-menu:not(".dropdown-menu",this)').slideUp();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$(".dropdown").click(function () {
    var child = $(".dropdown-menu", this); //Store reference in a variable
    child.slideToggle(); //slide Toggle
    $('.dropdown-menu').not(child).slideUp(); //Slide up others
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dropdown-menu").not(this).slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
     $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp();
     $(this).slideDown();
});
```